# RESTEasy - Getting entire query string

Tags: rest, web-services, get, resteasy

I would like to get the entire query string in a GET method. For example, if the uri is

host:port/app?param1=123&param2=xyz&param3=4

I would like to get the "param1=123&param2=xyz&param3=4" part. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get get [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), where you will find everything. For example, in your resource:

```
public class MyResource {
  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest request;
  @GET
  public void get() {
    this.request.getQueryString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

really old... but:

you should map the @Context and get the query portion as follows:
.getRequestUri().getQuery()

```
    @POST
    @Path("/{path}")
    public Response transform(@PathParam String path, @Context UriInfo uriInfo, String inputData) {
...
        String query = uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery();
        System.out.println(query); // null if no query parameter is supplied
...
```